# How to create JavaScript REPL that will work with let and const?

Tags: javascript, scope, read-eval-print-loop

I have [simple JavScript REPL](https://try.javascript.org.pl/):

```js
function(command) {
     if (command !== '') {
         try {
             var result = window.eval(command);
             if (result) {
                 if (result instanceof $.fn.init) {
                     this.echo(`#&lt;jQuery&gt;`);
                 } else if (typeof result === 'object') {
                     var name = result.constructor.name;
                     if (name) {
                         this.echo(`#&lt;${name}&gt;`);
                     } else {
                         this.echo(result.toString());
                     }
                 } else {
                     this.echo(new String(result));
                 }
             }
         } catch(e) {
             this.error(new String(e));
         }
     }
 }
```

But it doesn't work with let or const:

```
js> let x = 10
js> x
ReferenceError: x is not defined
js>
```

Is there a hack that will make this work? I have no idea how Google Chrome Dev Tools make it work. It will probably take a long time to read the code. Just want to ask before I will possibly spend a lot of time reading it's code.

I know that I can just replace `let` with `var` before evaluation, but I don't like this solution.

**EDIT**: the answers to duplicated question only show why `let` and `const` doesn't work in `eval`, but don't answer how to make eval work with `let` or `const`, like in Dev Tools. My question is: how to make `eval` work with `let` and `const`.

Comment: I have no idea who vote to close the question. This is single question how to make `window.eval` work with `let` and `const`? I don't see any other question here.

Comment: You don't, for the reasons stated. The dev console doesn't use `eval` in the same way a userscript does (if it does at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Someone posted on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/rjsw6a/askjs_contextpreserving_eval/) this code:

```js
var __EVAL = (s) => eval(`void (__EVAL = ${__EVAL}); ${s}`);

__EVAL("const a = 42;"); // undefined
__EVAL("a;"); // 42
```

And it do exactly what I need.

The source of this code came from answer to this question: [Context-preserving eval](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67322922/387194) (as noted by the OP on Reddit).

**EDIT**:

For future reference, because I will delete this code, I'm posting the solution I was using:

```js
 const context = {
     __$$__: {},
     ...globals(),
     $,
     console: {
         log(...args) {
             console.log(...args);
             term.echo(args.map(repr).join(' '));
         }
     }
 };
 function unset(context, name) {
     delete context[name];
 }
 function exec(code, ctx = context) {
     ctx = {...ctx};
     code = patch(code, ctx)
     return vm.runInNewContext(code, ctx);
 }

 function is_scoped(name, context) {
     return name in context.__$$__;
 }
 function patch(code, context) {
     let patching = [];
     let result = falafel(code, function(node) {
         if (node.type == 'VariableDeclaration') {

             node.declarations.forEach(declaration => {
                 const name = declaration.id.name;
                 if (is_scoped(name, context)) {
                     unset(context, name);
                 }
                 patching.push(`__$$__.${name} = ${name}`);
             });
         } else if (node.type === 'Identifier' &&
                    is_scoped(node.name, context) &&
                    node.parent.type !== 'VariableDeclarator') {
             const name = node.name;
             node.update(`__$$__.${name}`);
         }
     });
     result = result.toString();
     if (patching.length) {
         result += ';' + patching.join(';');
     }
     return result;
 }
```

Using vm node module (part of browserify) and node-falafel converted using browserify as well.