# Custom Node JS REPL input/output stream

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, node-modules, read-eval-print-loop, node-repl

I need to have custom REPL input/output stream. for example I need to pass a piece of script to the REPL when some event happens and get it's output and do something with it.

---

To describe it more clear to you, I'm working on a [vscode plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MohammadMD.js-interactive) *[(github: source code)](https://github.com/MohammadMD1383/js-interactive)* which provides REPL. in my case I have a `vscode WebView` and from there, I get user input and then I want to pass that input to the node REPL and get its output and show it to user.

So, how would I achieve that? *If you need more information please tell me. thanks in advance.*

**EDIT 1:**

```
const replServer = repl.start({
    input: /* what should be here? */,
    output: /* what should be here? */
});
```

**Edit 2:**
*can anyone explain me what is the usage of `input`/`output` parameters in the above example?*

Comment: how did you solve this problem?

Comment: @KelvinOmereshone this problem didn't solved as I was expecting; instead I created a custom VM. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67173347/javascript-do-all-evaluations-in-one-vm and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67322922/context-preserving-eval

Comment: Interesting I was able to supply custom streams myself and it works but the issue of scope came up as if I declare a variable in the first run that variable will be said to be declared already even after exiting and restarting the REPL

Comment: @KelvinOmereshone so can you share your approach with us as an answer to this question? it will be valuable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that worked for me.

```js
const {
    PassThrough
} = require('stream')
const repl = require('repl')


const input = new PassThrough()
const output = new PassThrough()

output.setEncoding('utf-8')



const _repl = repl.start({
    prompt: 'awesomeRepl> ',
    input,
    output
})

_repl.on('exit', function() {
    // Do something when REPL exit
    console.log('Exited REPL...')
})


function evaluate(code) {
    let evaluatedCode = ''
    output.on('data', (chunk) => {
        evaluatedCode += chunk.toString()
        console.log(evaluatedCode)

    })

    input.write(`${code}\n`)
    return result

}

evaluate('2 + 2') // should return 4
```

Notice created the REPL instance outside the `evaluate` function so we don't create a new instance for every call of `evaluate`

Comment: `evaluate` is confusing and doesn't work. What is the idea behind `result`?

Answer (score 1):

1. To create a repl server you just need to do

```
const repl = require('repl')
repl.start({prompt: "> ", input: input_stream, output: output_stream");
```

prompt is a string that is the prompt, stream is the input. `input_stream` needs to be a readable stream, `output_stream` needs to be a writable one. you can read more about streams [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html). Once the streams are working you can do

```
output_stream.on('data', (chunk) => {                                                                                                                                                            
   14   //whatever you do with the data                                                                                                                                                                     
   15 });
```

Comment: hmmm... everything looks good but just a little question: In the documentation I see `getWritableStreamSomehow();`. How should I create a stream? not getting it from somewhere.

Comment: And then how to pass a string to `readable stream`. I mean sth like this: `readableStream.read("hello world")`. then this should be interpreted by `repl`.

Comment: I linked the node docs, you should be able to get else you need there

Comment: To create a writable stream do `const writable = new stream.Writable();`